# sqlite studio user defined function

Tags: sqlite

sqlite studio does not support square root function, so i have defined it in function editor as

```
    proc SqrtA {num} {  set ans [expr {sqrt($num)}] return $ans }
```

with function name SqrtA and one input argument, lang. tcl
but when i am using it in query editor, i am not getting the square root.

for example i had tried for -

```
    select SqrtA(9);
```

can anyone please help me, in how to include square root function in sqlite studio?